# How to fill cells of a GridView with lists of names?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `GridView`, each cell of  which I would like to populate with a list of names, and I need these lists to be dynamically changeable. I tried implementing this idea as follows:

```
public void fillBoard(int groupSize){
    int numGroups = listPresentMembers.size()/groupSize;
    ListView [] groups = new ListView [numGroups];


    for(int i=0;i<numGroups;i++){
        String [] items = new String[groupSize];
        for(int j=0;j<groupSize;j++){

          items[j] = listPresentMembers.get(i*groupSize + j);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,items);
        groups[i] = new ListView(this);
        groups[i].setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<ListView> groupsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListView>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,groups);

    gridViewBoard.setAdapter(groupsAdapter);
}
```

The essential idea is that I create an `ArrayAdapter` of type `ListView`, each item of which is defined by one of the groups of names I would like to populate a particular cell of the `GridView`. I then set this `ArrayAdapter` to my `GridView`.

The problem is that when I run the app, the elements of the `GridView` are strings such as 
"android.widget.ListView@41bcfa60". Where did I go wrong?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: whenever you see something like "android.widget.ListView@41bcfa60", it means that something in your code was expecting a String and you gave it an object (in this case, a ListView) instead.

So what happened?  Take a look at the adapter for your GridView.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,items);
```

Here's the constructor for the ArrayAdapter you're using:

> **public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)**
>
> *Parameters*
>
> `context`  The current context.
>
> `resource` The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
>
> `textViewResourceId`   The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
>
> `objects`  The objects to represent in the ListView.

You're passing `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as the `resource`, which means it's the layout you're using.  This layout consists of a single TextView--a single line of text.  *It is not designed to hold a ListView.*

When this layout wants to populate the TextView (the `textViewResourceId`), it looks at the appropriate element of the array (`items`) that you passed in and tries to get text out of it--in Java we do this by calling toString() on an object.  If toString() is not implemented, by default it returns something like the "android.widget.ListView@41bcfa60" gibberish that you got.

That's the why, but I think your code has bigger problems.  If I were you, I'd strongly reconsider a design that involves a GridView where each grid item is a ListView.  That is not conventional at all, so there's probably a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.  Consider posting another question explaining your goal and asking for code design help.

Comment: Thanks Amanda, that is quite helpful. In terms of design help, maybe I could pester you in the comments before making a full question? Essentially, I would like to model something like a tournament: each row of the gridview is a time slot, and each cell specifies say the 4 people playing at the location indicated by the column. I suppose I could put each person in a cell if that's the more recommended way, but is the basic idea here not appropriate for my purposes? Thanks!

Comment: Like a ListView, a GridView is designed to show a series of items.  Conventionally, the row and column of each grid item is arbitrary.  Think of a photo app--usually the gallery will be a series of photos arranged in a grid, and the row and column of each photo is meaningless.  It sounds like the information you're trying to display should be in a *table*, not a *grid*.  Check out Android's `TableLayout`.

Comment: okay thanks. I've never used TableLayout before ... will I be able to have a dynamically varying number of rows, and is it easy enough to define the number of columns in the onCreate method of my activity (I cannot define it in xml since it must depend on user input)?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to do both of those...  But this is turning into a complicated question.  I think you should post another question, with an explanation of what you want the screen to look like  (you might get the best answers by providing a [mockup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460624/tools-for-creating-mockups-for-android-mobile)), and asking for specific design advice.