# Design advice for TableLayout (or possibly GridView)

Tags: android, gridview, tablelayout

I was kindly advised to ask for design help for the following problem.

I have a list of names, which may expand/change dynamically on user input, and I wish to arrange these names into n groups each of size s (don't worry about remainders). Call this a "partition".

I would like to do this cyclically, i.e. there will be a first partition, a second partition, etc ... I would like to display the partitions in some sort of grid, with each row corresponding to a different partition and each column corresponding to the elements of a given partition.

My first thought was a `GridView`, but I tried organizing the list of names corresponding to each cell of the `GridView` into a `ListView` and [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903775/1393860) this does not work. I was advised to use a `TableLayout` instead, where I suppose each name will have to occupy a single cell.

I am curious

1. Is `TableLayout` the best choice for my purposes?
2. If so, must/should every name be in it's own cell?
3. Will changing the number of rows/columns dynamically be an issue with `TableLayout`?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

http://androidexample.com/Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=75&aaid=99

check this link .as my think ur problem may be solve